# NSPredicate with dynamic key and value

Tags: ios, core-data, filter, nspredicate

I am trying to create a function that searches through my core data stack and return the amount of messages for a desired key/value.

Here is my code:

```
NSFetchRequest      *messagesCountRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Message"];
NSEntityDescription *messageCountModel    = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Message" inManagedObjectContext:_mainManagedObjectContext];

[messagesCountRequest setEntity:messageCountModel];

NSPredicate *messageCountPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@", key, value];

[messagesCountRequest setPredicate:messageCountPredicate];

count = (int)[_mainManagedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:messagesCountRequest error:nil];
```

The problem is that it returns 0 every time. I have located the source of the problem. When have a static key, the predicate looks like this.

```
key == "value"
```

When I pass through a dynamic key, it looks like this

```
"key" == "value"
```

So the problem appears to be the first set of double quotes around the key that is placed by passing a NSString to the predicate. How would I fix this?

**EDIT: For clarity, I need it to be like the first case, that is the one that works.**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To substitute a *key* in the predicate string, you have to use `%K`, not `%@`:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key, value];
```

From the [Predicate Format String Syntax documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html):

> - %@ is a var arg substitution for an object value—often a string, number, or date.
> - %K is a var arg substitution for a key path.

Comment: +1 I never knew about this and it actually fixes a problem I was having the other day trying to do exactly this. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF[%@] CONTAINS %@",key,value)
```

This worked for me