# Concatenate string NSPredicate not work correctly objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, concatenation, nspredicate

This is my first question, but I don't found the answer.

I develop my app in obj-c for iOS platform, I initialize a `NSPredicate` object in this mode:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%@ IN (%@)", uniquePropertyKey, valuesWithDupes];
```

where `uniquePropertyKey` is a `NSString` with name property and `valuesWithDupes` is a `NSArray` with objects.

If uniquePropertyKey value is NAME in predicate I have something as `"NAME" in {"1", "n"}`
but I want  `NAME in {"1", "n"}`, why in predicate concatenate strings format add quotes (") at my value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSPredicate with dynamic key and value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387925/nspredicate-with-dynamic-key-and-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you are using the dynamic value assigned to the predicate directly with NSSString stringWithFormat and using %@ as the substitution for the dynamic replacement. For the key portion if you make it %K, this will work fine. So, you predicate would be,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K IN (%@)", uniquePropertyKey, valuesWithDupes];
```

Comment: Thank you! It's work fine! I don't know this format: %K.

Answer (score 0):

I have used predicate in my Project like for filter array by category using predicate

```
    NSString *selectedCategory = activity.user_id;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id == %@", selectedCategory];

    NSArray *filteredArray = [self.array_selectedActivities filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This works for me!